# 念 vs 读 What is the difference?

Tags: grammar

My thoughts are 念 specifically means reading out loud, emphasis on "out loud".

读 can be out loud or to oneself, the emphasis is just on "reading".

If I want someone to read something out loud for me I would say 给我念一下 , but if I say 给我读一下 would that also be interpreted as "read it out loud to me" ?

Comment: I add a tag, lexical.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can 念 something without looking at the words, e.g. 念經，念咒， 念詩 (chanting scriptures, chanting spells, reciting poetry)

you must look at the words to 读 (read) something, e.g. 讀書，讀報紙

both 念 and 讀 can be done 'out loud' or 'in the mind' therefore, we have phrases like 回家把課文讀幾遍， 把課文讀出來，朗聲念詩，  and 默念詩句

Answer (score 2):

The two verbs 念 and 读 have the same meaning in most cases and can be used interchangeably. They both mean "read" in English. The differences between them could be listed as the following.

(1) **念** means read with voice. **读** means read with or without voice. For example,

请把这封信给我**念**一下. (我的眼睛花了, 看不清字了. ) Please read the letter to me. (My eyes are blurred and I can't read the words clearly.)

Using **读** in this sentence is OK because people understand that you must read it with your voice to let the other party hear it.

(2) 你学习的时候，请不要**念**出声来，影响别人。When you are studying, please don't read it aloud to affect others.

(3) **读** can be used in compound words such as 阅读 (read), 朗读(read aloud), 默读(silently read), 速读(speed read), etc. The compound words are somehow fixed, you could not use 念 in those words.

(4) 念书, as a compound word, means "go to school". For example,

小孩子应该念书, 不应该种地. Children should study, not do farm work.

(5) The word **读** has the mood of reading attentively, carefully, and thoughtfully. For example,

你只是把文章**念**了一遍，并没有**读**懂作者的意思。You just looked through the article but didn't understand the meaning of the author.

In the sentence, **念** means "glance through", not necessarily "read aloud". Using **念** here is to highlight **读** in contrast.

Comment: Isn't 默念 a valid word? https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E9%BB%98%E5%BF%B5/1383034

Answer (score 1):

The main differences between 念 and 读:

念 - The action of **reading with or without comprehending** the material.

读 - The action of **reading and comprehending** the material.

Answer (score 1):

读 is reading, while 念 is reciting from memory without referring to the text.

念 can also mean rememberance, depending on the context.

Answer (score 1):

They correspond roughly to the English *recite* vs *read*.

(In English, we can say both "Recite for me" or "Read for me". In Mandarin, we can also say both 给我念一下  and 给我读一下. In both English and Mandarin, recite/念 strongly suggests but does not mandate doing so out loud.)

Answer (score 1):

You may look hinative.com/questions/15426.

There seems to be some confusion here between "read" and "recite". "read" is not the same as "recite", at least not in English.

Neither 念 nor 读 on their own mean 'recite'.

They are more or less the same until you use them in combination to make other 2 character words.

请再给我念一遍。
Please read it back to me.

请再给我读一遍。
Please read it back to me.

Answer (score 1):

I think "念“ is more like an order.like the teacher asks students to do something.And it makes people feel uncomfortable.But "读” is used in most situations.

ps: I live in china for 10 years.hope i can help you .